# Select All <tds> in Row of Same Button onClick

Tags: jquery, html

Good afternoon! I have a table with rows being added with AJAX calls. These tables have a checkbox button. I want to call another AJAX function on a button click and pass the value of the first `TD` in the same row as the selected checkbox into the function. I know how to do most of it, but what I can't figure out is whether there's a way to get a jQuery object of the row in which a selected checkbox resides? Additionally, why can't I use "this" like this?

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
        var parentRow = $(this).parent();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.closest()`

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
        var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Or selector only:

```
$("tr:contains(input:checked)")
```